# Question on the equivalent definition of $R$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

Let $R$ be a *commutative* ring with $1_R$.

I found the following theorem as an equivalent definition of $R-$modules.

> **Theorem.** An abelian group $(M,+)$ is an $R$-module iff there is a ring homomorphism $\varphi:R\longrightarrow \mathrm{End}_R(M)$.

The proof is not difficult but let me ask something.

Could we claim that the theorem is still valid, if $R$ is not commutative? So, left $R-modules are in general different from the right.

And if the answer is yes, if we have an abelian group $(M,+)$, and there exists a homomorphism $\varphi:R\longrightarrow \mathrm{End}_R(M)$, then we can construct both left and right $R-$modules.

Is this right? Please, explain your answers please.

*Thank you.*

Comment: A left $R$-module structure would be equivalent to a ring morphism $R \to \operatorname{End}_{Ab}(M)$; on the other hand, a right $R$-module structure would be equivalent to a ring morphism $R^{op} \to \operatorname{End}_{Ab}(M)$ where $R^{op}$ is "$R$ with multiplication reversed".

Comment: The theorem is stated extremely poorly.  It's not clear what "an abelian group $(M,+)$ is an $R$-module" is supposed to even mean.  There is an interpretation for which the theorem is correct, but that interpretation would not make this "an equivalent definition of $R$-modules".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An abelian group $M$ can be given the structure of $R$-module if and only if there exists a ring homomorphism
$$
\varphi\colon R\to\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)
$$
If $M$ is given a structure of $R$-module, then the homomorphism $\varphi$ is defined by $\phi(r)\colon x\mapsto rx$. Conversely, given the ring homomorphism $\varphi$, we can define $rx=\varphi(r)(x)$.

It is true that *if* $M$ has already been given the structure of $R$-module, then there exists a ring homomorphism $R\to\operatorname{End}_{R}(M)$ (for commutative $R$), but without a previous $R$-module structure, $\operatorname{End}_{R}(M)$ doesn't make sense, so the statement cannot be “if and only if”.

By the way, there could be *different* ring homomorphisms $R\to\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$, giving rise to different structures of $R$-modules on the abelian group $M$.

If you write maps on the left, then the condition about ring homomorphisms works also without the assumption that $R$ is commutative and defines *left* $R$-modules.

A structure of right $R$-module is given by a ring homomorphism $\psi\colon R^{\mathrm{op}}\to\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$, where $R^{\mathrm{op}}$ is the opposite ring (with the same addition and multiplication $(r,s)\mapsto sr$).

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. So, the statement should be "An abelian group M can be given the structure of $R$-module if and only if there exists a ring homomorphism $φ:R→\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$". Is this for a random unital ring $R$? 2) Could you, please, remind me the ring $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$? Is this the ring consisting of all endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ ?

Comment: @Chris $R$ being unital is actually not relevant, but non unital rings are a big nuisance. The endomorphism ring $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ is indeed formed by the endomorphisms as abelian group (or, which is the same, as $\mathbb{Z}$-module). Note that there exists a unique (unital) ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to any ring, in particular to $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$.

Comment: Dear egreg, could you please verify if the statement in my answer is OK now? Of course the "credits" are yours! :)

Comment: @Chris Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more question. Could you please explain why $\mathrm{End}_R(M) \subseteq \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ is subring of $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$?

Comment: @Chris It’s a direct check: composition of two $R$-linear maps is $R$-linear

Answer (score 0):

*Let me give a try to answer and improve the theorem. Please feel free to edit my answer.*

**Theorem.** Let $R$ be a ring with $1_R$ and $(M,+)$ an abelian group ($\iff \mathbb{Z}$-module). Then,

1. (i) For every $x\in R$, there is a map
   \begin{align}
   μ_x:M&\longrightarrow M, \\
   m& \longmapsto μ_x(m):=x\cdot m
   \end{align}
   which is an endomorphism of abelian groups. That is, $μ_x \in \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M) $.

(ii) The map 
\begin{align}
μ:R&\longrightarrow \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M),\\
r&\longmapsto μ(x):= μ_x : M \longrightarrow M, \ m  \longmapsto μ_x(m):=x\cdot m\\
\end{align}
is a ring homomorphism.

2. Let $ν:R\longrightarrow  \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ a ring homomorphism. Then $(M,+)$ together with the scalar multiplication

\begin{align}
\cdot :R \times M &\longrightarrow M, \\
(r,m)& \longmapsto r\cdot m:= ν(r)(m)
\end{align}
is an $R$-module.